# programmatically update page's source by adding/removing links to external scripts.

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have some web pages that will link to a javascript document on my server, which will give some functionality to those pages. I need to be able to change the name of this js document over time. What can I include within that js doc, to modify the page which linked to it, updating that link? For example, a page links to my js thusly

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mysite.com/directory.filename.js"></script>
```

How can my js within that doc modify that page's source, permanently replacing this link with a new/correct one?

I want this to all work automatically, so the webmasters of those pages wont need to be constantly editing their source manually. They just include the first link one time. It updates itself periodically, and then when the webmaster decides they dont want my functionality anymore, they simply remove the link manually from their source.

Answer (score 2):

**You have 3 options here.**

**1. A txt file with the URL.**

You can store a `.txt` file **with a constant name** that contains the path of the JS file. Then you do the following:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/<?php echo file_get_contents("jsname.txt"); ?>"></script>`

Extra info: [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)
If this is cross-domain this method won't work.

**2. PHP Redirect**

You can have a PHP file on your site which redirects to the correct one and you update it whenever you want.
For instance:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/myjs_redirect.php"></script>`

You change the `.php` file's redirect to point to the correct JS file each time.
Example PHP code:

`header("Location: myJS.js");`

**3. Mod_Rewrite Redirect**

You can use `.htaccess` to redirect this. Put it in the same folder as the JS file, and add the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^my_standard_js_URL\.js$ mynewJSfile.js [L]
```

**If you like the 3rd option (I recommend it), please consider retagging this question.**

Comment: thanks for your answer - some fine ideas. I'm wondering though, if it's possible to update the referring webpage's actual source code. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Nope, sorry. They own the file and have the permissions to edit it; you don't (if you do, please let me know). The best you can do is redirect them to the right page - minimal performance loss can be achieved with Mod_Rewrite.